# Having trouble on understanding some parts of Pedersen's explanation of constructing a locally convex topological vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

This is what I have constructed so far.

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\{m_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a separating family of semi-norms on $V$. Define $$f_{i, y}(x) := m_i(x - y)$$We can show that the collection of $f_{i, y}$ is a separating family on $V$. Suppose that $x \neq y$. Hence, $x - z \neq y - z$. There exists $i \in I$ such that $$f_{i, z}(x) = m_i(x - z) \neq m_i(y - z) = f_{i, z}(y)$$We can consider the initial topology i.e. the weakest topology on $X$ that makes every function in our collection $\{f_{i, y}\}_{i \in I, y \in V}$ continuous.

He then states that sets of this form a subbasis for the neighborhood filter $\mathcal{O}(x)$.

$$\{y \in V: |m_i(y - z) - m_i(x - z)| < \epsilon\} $$
I understand that these sets will be in the subbasis of my weakest topology. However, shouldn't there be more sets in my subbasis that contain $x$? We can view
$$ \{y \in V: |m_i(y - z) - m_i(x - z)| < \epsilon\} = f_{i, z}^{-1}(B(m_i(x - z), \epsilon))$$
Couldn't we have some open ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ that's center isn't $m_i(x - z)$? The thing that I was having trouble on understand was that Pedersen doesn't seem to be using on open sets $U$ in $\mathbb{R}_\geq$ where $x \in f_{i, z}^{-1}(U)$.

I felt that I understood the rest of Pedersen's explanation of the construction of a locally convex topological vector space from a collection of semi-norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in f^{-1}_{i, z}(U)$, then $f_{i, z}(x)\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $I=(f_{i, z}(x)-\varepsilon, f_{i, z}(x)+\varepsilon)\subset U$, and so $f^{-1}_{i, z}(I)\subset f^{-1}_{i, z}(U)$. But $f^{-1}_{i, z}(I)=\{y\in V:\, |f_{i, z}(y)-f_{i, z}(x)|<\varepsilon\}$. So it is enough to consider sets of the type $f^{-1}_{i, z}(I)$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: That makes complete sense, but $f_{i, z}(U)$ still should be in my subbasis. I know that the subbase from the initial topology covers $X$(the reason why I bring that up is that not all subbasis cover $X$). So when you mean enough are you saying that the collection of sets $\{f_{i, z}^{-1}(I)\}_{i \in I,z \in V}$ and the collection from my initial topology subbasis that contains $x$ are both subbases for $x$ i.e. the collection of finite intersections of them both produce neighborhood basis of $x$?

Comment: Just for clarification when I mean the subbasis of my initial topology I mean $\{f_{i, z}^{-1}(U): z \in V, i \in I, U \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}}\}$

Comment: You can have different subbases for the same topology. For example in a metric space, a subbasis at $x$ could be all balls centered at x, but another one could be all balls with rational radius centered at x. What the book is saying is that you can choose another smaller subbasis